# Kotlin Extension Functions Databinding

Tags: mvvm, kotlin, extension-function

Is there any possibility to use extension function with a databinding?
XML:

```
<data>
    <import type="my.package.domain.country.model.City.streetName" />

    <variable
        name="city"
        type="my.package.domain.country.model.City" />
</data>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{city.street.streetName()}" />
```

my.package.domain.country.model.city

```
data class City(
        val id: String,
        val street: Street
) 

fun City.streetName(): String = street.houseNumber
```

Error

> [kapt] An exception occurred:
>   android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding
>   errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method streetName() in class my.package.domain.country.model.City

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You have to import CityKt firstly into xml

```
<import type="my.package.domain.country.model.CityKt" />
```

int the data section
then you can use it like this

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/city"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@{CityKt.streetName(city)}" />
```

If you review CityKt you will see that there is static Java method with City as first argument

Comment: Thanks for this, was wrapping my extension calls in model classes. Saves a lot of time!

Comment: Can instance methods be also used with data binding ?

Answer (score 17):

While @skiff2011 is correct, one could also use `alias` to prevent the `Kt` postfix.

For example, a certain extension function is located in `ExtensionFunctionsKt` can be aliased by `ExtensionFunctions`

```
<import
    alias="ExtensionFunctions"
    type="com.helloworld.app.util.ExtensionFunctionsKt" />

<variable
    name="someData"
    type="com.helloworld.app.model.SomeData" />
```

The `ExtensionFunction` alias can now be used to call the extension function. The first argument still needs to be the extended class variable.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{ExtensionFunctions.doStuff(someData)}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Extension function

Ex:

```
fun Context.isDarkMode(): Boolean {

 }
```

Now we have Extenstion function for dark mode which can be accessed using context.

Usually in Kotlin class we can access using context obj like below.

```
context.isDarkMode()
```

But in Xml,we can't access like above.

We need to import Extension function by appending KT to class.

**Ex)** If your file name is Extensions,then import should be ExtensionsKt.

Import like below in xml.

```
 <import type="com.example.extensions.ExtensionsKt" />
```

And then we can access Extension function like below i.e we need to pass object for which we are creating Extension i.e in our case it is context.

```
  app:context='@{(ExtensionsKt.isDarkMode(context)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Utils class you can to this:

```
 object Utils(){
       fun streetName(): String {}
}

<import
    type="com.helloworld.app.util.Utils" />



  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{Utils.INSTANCE.streetName()}"
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use view model for to call extension functions.