# Call extension in data binding expression

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-extension

I was wondering if there is any way we can call extensions in expression attribs,

For Eg, here is some extension

```
fun String.parseServerDate():String{
 ...
}
```

To call while in kotlin, we use `myTime.parseServerDate()`

So, my problem is how can I call this extension within in expression language

Tried `@{mydate.parseServerDate()}` which is not working

I tried importing my extension kt file in `<import>` tag, but nothing seems to be happening

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin databinding with extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589320/kotlin-databinding-with-extension-methods)

Comment: Please post your xml file and consider reading about Binding adapters: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

Answer (score 2):

You can't use extension functions in XML

what you can do is create a data binding adapter for whatever you want to do with the view or make an object and put the function inside it so you can use it where ever you like

```
object Functions{
   fun parseServerDate(string : String) {
   ...
   }
}



//in xml

<import type="the object path"/>

@{Functions.parseServerDate(data.string)}
```

in order for me to help you more you must be more specific about what you want to do i.e what the extension function does

you can read about binding adapters here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

Comment: Thanks, but I know this approach. I was wondering if I can reuse my extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say your extension method is defined in `ExtensionMethod.kt`
Import the kt file like so

```
<import type="yourpackage.ExtensionMethodKt"/>
```

Then while calling your extension use the below format

```
@{ExtensionMethodKt.parseServerDate(mydate)}
```

This should solve your problem!

Comment: Perhaps you should read the last line of my question, I already tried this but it won't work

Comment: @Aziz
After importing are you calling your extension fun like `@{mydate.parseServerDate()}` or `@{ExtensionMethodKt.parseServerDate(mydate)}
`?

Comment: @Aziz
Check this post if you haven't already.  - 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898669/kotlin-extension-functions-databinding